# How to skip table in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, create-table

I create a table using MySQL

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE Register "
```

inside PHP file.

then I have INSERT data in the table using INSERT code.

insert recode successfully ,but i can insert data only one time .another time server display "massage err Table 'register' already exists . "

how can i slove this problem.i want code for

```
if( table is alredy in database )
{
    don't create new one 
}

else 
{    
     create database 
}
```

tell me how can i complete

Comment: Generally your application wouldn't need to create tables on a regular basis. If you find yourself doing this then it might be a symptom of a design flaw. What was the reason for having the table creation in your code?

Comment: @ADyson probably some migration scripts

Comment: problem was finished

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean my question isn't valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for PHP logic here. MySQL's [`create table`  statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) accepts option `if not exists`, so you can just do:

```
create table if not exists register (
    -- your table definition goes here
);
```

If the table does not exists, it is created. If it already exists, the statement turns to a no-op and returns without failing.

Comment: err You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'if not exists( number INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ...' at line 1              this error has come

Comment: @kavindu: my bad, I misplaced the option (it goes before the table name). Fixed.

Comment: It works but error in INSERT Option ....Error create recodeINSERT INTO Register(number,fistname,lastname,email,password) VALUES ('645','kavindu','hj','hjh@gmail.com','aa')

Comment: @kavindu: that is a different problem clearly. I would recomment asking a new question for this, providing all necessary debugging details.